# Powershell not capturing colorized Git output

Tags: git, powershell

I'm executing the following command in Powershell.

```
 git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline
```

The goal is to get all non-pushed commits on all branches.  Git displays the name of the branch in the output (in a different color).
When I try to capture the command with

```
 $foo = git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline
```

the variable `$foo` is missing the colored output.  So it's not the same as what gets displayed on the screen.

How can I capture the same output that would be displayed?

**Update**
Just to clarify, I don't care about the output being in color.  My point was only that the colored output is not being captured at all, in color or not

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I clarified your question title. Powershell is capturing all the output, just not in color. I'm curious as well.

Comment: Try the parameter `--decorate=short`. You can also use `full`

Comment: How would colors be represented in plain-text output?

Comment: No, it is not capturing all output.  I don't care so much about the color. My point is only that the colored output is not being captured at all.

Comment: I think `--decorate=short` did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a PowerShell issue but actually with Git. Git changes the output depending on how the output is processed. In GNU/Linux, for example:

```
$ git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline
314129a (HEAD -> master) Generate Bootstrap rules with mode classes.
...
```

If I pipe it through `cat` for example then the output changes to:

```
$ git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline | cat
314129a Generate Bootstrap rules with mode classes.
...
```

It wasn't just the colour in your example as the parantheses were removed as well.

What you are seeing in PowerShell is the same behaviour:

```
PS> git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline
d331837 (HEAD -> master) Fixed issue with comparisons.
```

And then piped through something:

```
PS> git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline | Out-String
d331837 Fixed issue with comparisons.
```

And so to fix the problem you need to tell Git to generate output in a specific way, e.g.

```
$foo = git log --branches --not --remotes --oneline --decorate=short
```